# Remove simple product from grouped product during csv import in magento 2

Tags: csv, product, magento-2.3, grouped-list

I have added some associated_sku (of simple products) to one grouped product & removed it from another grouped product.
Actually I wrongly associated a simple product to a grouped product initially in my CSV file. I wanted to remove it from the old grouped product and add it to the new one.

My import behavior is Add or Update.

But after importing all data. I see the newly associated/added simple products are showing with the new grouped product as these should. But these are not removed from the old grouped product from which I have removed it from associated_sku column. How I can achieve this?

Comment: What is the best solution for this? Should I remove simple products from grouped products (Can I do this?) ?.. Or any other solution...

Answer (score 0):

Following link help me alot to achieve what is needed. It is clear we can achieve it only by programmatically removing these in magento. With current import behaviour "Add|Update" only this solution is possible.

https://minhducnho.wordpress.com/2018/02/13/magento-2-remove-unlink-child-product-from-grouped-product-programmatically/

But, the code mentioned is very specific. You need to created $product at the top and little more adjustments accordingly.